# Is there any possibility that `vptr` is modified outside of constructor and destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, destructor

I'm reading topics related to object destruction in the book *Inside C++ Object Model* and encounter this problem.

It says that before the execution of user-defined destructor, the destructor will be augmented. The first step of the augmentation is reset the `vptr` pointer to the virtual function table of that class. I remember that correspondingly, just before the execution of user code (statements in the blocked constructor body) in the constructor, the `vptr` has already been properly set in case virtual member functions should be invoked during construction.

The problem is whether the reset `vptr` step in the destructor augmentation is a must.
If so, there must be some possibility that the `vptr` in an object be updated somewhere.
When may this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen in the destructor of a derived class. Say you have:

```
class Foo : public Bar : public Baz
```

Now, say you have a `Foo`. In `Foo::~Foo`, it's a `Foo`, and that's the virtual function table it must use. But when `Foo::~Foo` completes, it's not a `Foo` anymore. It's a `Bar`, and that's what virtual function table it must use. When `Bar::~Bar` completes, it's just a `Baz`, so in `Baz::~Baz`, it must use the virtual function table for `Baz`.

The pointer to the virtual function table does not change except when in constructors and destructors.

Here's some example code to play with:

```
    #include <string>  
    #include <iostream>

    class Foo
    {
    public:
        Foo() { print("Foo::Foo"); }
        virtual ~Foo() { print("Foo::~Foo"); }
        virtual void print(std::string j) { std::cout << j << "(Foo)" << std::endl; }
    };

    class Bar : public Foo
    {
    public:
        Bar() { print("Bar::Bar"); }
        virtual ~Bar() { print("Bar::~Bar"); }
        virtual void print(std::string j) { std::cout << j << "(Bar)" << std::endl; }
    };

    class Baz : public Bar
    {
    public:
        Baz() { print("Baz:Baz"); }
        virtual ~Baz() { print("Baz::~Baz"); }
        virtual void print(std::string j) { std::cout << j << "(Baz)" << std::endl; }
    };

    int main(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructing Baz" << std::endl;
        {
            Baz j;
            std::cout << "Baz constructed" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Baz destructed" << std::endl;
    }
```

Output is:

```
Constructing Baz
Foo::Foo(Foo)
Bar::Bar(Bar)
Baz:Baz(Baz)
Baz constructed
Baz::~Baz(Baz)
Bar::~Bar(Bar)
Foo::~Foo(Foo)
Baz destructed
```

You can see how a `Foo` is constructed and then used to make a `Bar` which is used to make the final `Baz`. At destruction time, `~Baz` turns it into a `Bar` and then `~Bar` turns it into a `Foo`. `~Foo` does the final destruction.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such possibility. The `vptr` is only updated from constructor and from destructor.

The update from destructor is done for a very specific reason: to make sure that all virtual functions called from inside the destructor of class `A` will call virtual functions defined in `A` or higher in the hierarchy, but not functions from classes located lower in the hierarchy. Basically, this is the same (symmetrical) reason why `vptr` pointer is updated in each constructor as well.

For example, in this hierarchy

```
struct A {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
  ~A() { foo(); }
};

struct B : A {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
  ~B() { foo(); }
};

struct C : B {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
  ~C() { foo(); }
};

C c;
```

Each destructor in the destructor chain for the object `c` will perform a call to virtual function `foo`. The destructor of `C` will call `C::foo`, the destructor of `B` will call `B::foo` (not `C::foo`) and the destructor of `A` will call `A::foo` (again, not `C::foo`). This happens that way specifically because each destructor explicitly sets the `vptr` pointer to the virtual table of its own class.

A more convoluted example of the same behavior might look as follows

```
struct A;
extern void (A::*fun)();

struct A {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
  ~A() { (this->*fun)(); }
};

void (A::*fun)() = &A::foo;

struct B : A {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
  ~B() { (this->*fun)(); }
};

struct C : B {
  virtual void foo() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
  ~C() { (this->*fun)(); }
};

C c;
```

The difference is that this example is more likely to physically use the `vptr` and the virtual method table to resolve the calls. The previous example is usually optimized by the compiler into direct non-virtual calls to proper `foo`.